# How would I code this using $.ajax instead of using async and fetch?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, fetch, async.js

```
async getDrinksByName(name){

    //Search by name

    const apiResponse = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}`);
```

Comment: `$.ajax()` returns a jQuery `Deferred` object, which can be used as a `Promise`. See the jQuery documentation for the parameters that it passes when the promise is resolved.

Comment: You an use options like `dataType: 'json'` to make it automatically parse a JSON response for you, analogous to calling `.json()` on the result of `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an easy fix:

```
// Get recipe by name
async getDrinksByName(name){
    //Search by name
    const apiResponse = await $.getJSON(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${name}`);

    // Return a json response

    const cocktails = await apiResponse;

    return{
        cocktails
    } 
}
```